# delete document on php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to delete a document with PHP. My database is Mongodb.

This is my database article : The collection is articles

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55be575271dd7ec905b7acda"), "title" : "test", "content" : "Test", "user" : "Paul", "saved_at" : ISODate("2015-08-02T17:49:45.776Z"),  }
>
```

So for example if I want to delete an article. I have tried this code :

ListArticle.php :

```
try {
           $connection = new MongoClient();
           $database   = $connection->selectDB('blog');
           $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
         } catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
           die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
            $query=array();
            $cursor=$collection->find($query);
            foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
                echo " Title : ".$doc['title']." "."by ".$doc['user'];                  
                ?>
                <form method="POST" action="script.php" onsubmit="return confirm('do you want to delete this article ?')">
                <br/>
                <?php 
                echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete'>";
                $v=$doc["content"];
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='content' value=$v>";
                echo "</form><br/>";
}
```

script.php :

```
try
            {
            $connection = new MongoClient();
            $database = $connection->selectDB('blog');
            }

        Catch(MongoException $e)
            {
            die("Failed to connect to database " . $e->getMessage());
            }

  $collection = $database->articles;



    $query=array("content"=>$_POST["content"]);
    $collection->remove($query);

    echo "<p>Success !</p>";


    ?>
```

When I click delete article it does not remove

Thanks with the help

Comment: Your code looks fine which means it is not a programming mistake

Comment: oh okay, I tried but the problem is that sometimes the articles removed and sometimes it does not delete it i don't know why :/

Comment: I would say the problem is in your value from `$_POST['content']`, it isn't matching due to something, maybe a space or something. It is normally a bad idea to match on a field like that for deletion

Comment: Also I have noticed your html is incorrect: `"<input type='hidden' name='content' value=$v>";` value needs string escaping like `value="$v"` and you probably need to `html_special_chars` the value as well since it could contain characters that will escape HTML

Comment: Can you write me exactly what I need to change please

Comment: I am not a freelancer, for one you are not paying me to code for you on demand. I have given you the info, you need to use your skills to complete the task. I have given you a solution, you just need to code it, most of which can be done by googling how to form HTML and the one function I said

Comment: where i put html_special_chars() ?